# How to make event only works on certain category discord.js v12

Tags: discord.js

so i want to make an event that only works on channels in certain category, here's my code

```
let categoryDiscuss = message.guild.channels.cache.get('category_id');

    if(message.content.includes('something') {
      if(message.author.bot) {
        return
      } else if(categoryDiscuss.type === "category"){
        const replyEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#4fbeff')
        .setDescription('some text')

        message.channel.send(replyEmbed)
      } else {
        return
      }
    }
```

the event is work but it still work on other channel inside other categories. Hope someone could help, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I am assuming there is other code playing a factor because this:

```js
let categoryDiscuss = message.guild.channels.cache.get('category_id');
```

would pull up a specific channel not a category

and this

```js
categoryDiscuss.type === "category"
```

would look for these channel types here to be true:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ChannelType

Whether that is the case or not I would code it this way:

```js
const categoryDiscuss = 'category_id'
// if you are hardcoding your category id number where category_id is

if (message.content.includes('something')) {
    if (message.author.bot) {
        return
    } else if (message.channel.parent.id === categoryDiscuss) {
        // if in the correct category by comparing the channels parent (category) to the one specified above and if it is in the right one
        const replyEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#4fbeff')
            .setDescription('some text')

        return message.channel.send({
            embeds: [replyEmbed]
        })
    } else {
        //if not in the correct category
        return
    }
}
```